# Where should I put logs in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, nlog

I use NLog as a logger for my WPF application. I configured it to store the log files in CommonApplicationData as you can see in my configuration.

```
fileName="${specialfolder:folder=CommonApplicationData}/MyApp/log.txt"
```

Which gives

```
C:\ProgramData\MyApp\log.txt
```

Its works fine with W7. However, it looks like it doesn't work on W8. I'm a little confused.

Does anyone know where should I put my log files on Windows 8? I would like to centralize my logs. Therefore, the folder need to be writeable by my application.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked for rights on folder ? I think it's write-protected, maybe your issue comes from here. Try to run your program as administrator or at least catch exceptions to know what happens.

Comment: I also think that the problem is related to the permission on the folder. However, I don't know how to make the folder writeable from a visual studio setup project. and I don't want to ask the user to run the software with Admin rights (maybe they don't have the rights either)

Comment: You won't be able to change permission rights on this folder without admin rights. You will have to store your logs in another unprotected folder. Maybe LocalApplicationData should be better.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try. The feedback will be long as I have to ship the application to the user.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I posted an answer containing what I told you above.

Comment: There's a chronic problem with c:\programdata, it is writable on too many programmer's machines.  No idea what kind of virus does this, I've personally never been infected.  Given the usage, it must be some kind of installer for a popular programming tool that does this.  Or these programmers just completely forgot that they are running VS elevated.  Log files belong in appdata.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to store files in your program without admin rights, you have to use an unprotected (ie writable for current user) folder. `LocalApplicationData` is here for this purpose.

You can also store it directly in `Documents` folder.